# How to make solr synonyms fetch same results(same number and ordering) both when searching with abbreviations and their full-names

Tags: solr

1. Have added the following in `schema.xml`:

   ```
   <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
       <analyzer type="index">
           <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
           <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
           <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
           <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>-->
           <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
          <!--<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>-->
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
   ```
2. `Synonym.txt`

   Attention deficit hyperactivity disorder,ADHD
3. `Re-indexed Solr`

But the number of results and the ordering is different when I search 'ADHD' and 'Attention deficit hyperactivity disorder'. Is there any more configurations that has to be done for the Solr to identify the synonym.txt and provide the same results for both the searches?

@dwhelan - the query for the search of ms looks like '((drug_facet_auto:((ms*)))OR(company_facet_auto:((ms*)))OR(disease_facet_auto:((ms*))))' and the QueryResponse : {responseHeader={status=0,QTime=15,params={facet=true,q=((drug_facet_auto:((ms*)))OR(company_facet_auto:((ms*)))OR(disease_facet_auto:((ms*)))),facet.limit=100,facet.field=[drug_facet, company_facet, disease_facet],wt=javabin,rows=0,version=2}},response={numFound=0,start=0,docs=[]},facet_counts={facet_queries={{!label='Last 24 hours'}publishdate:[NOW/HOUR-24HOURS TO NOW/HOUR+1HOUR]=0,{!label='Last 7 days'}publishdate:[NOW/DAY-7DAYS TO NOW/DAY+1DAY]=0,{!label='Last 30 days'}publishdate:[NOW/DAY-1MONTH TO NOW/DAY+1DAY]=0,{!label='Last year'}publishdate:[NOW/DAY-1YEAR TO NOW/DAY+1DAY]=0},facet_fields={drug_facet={},company_facet={},disease_facet={}},facet_dates={},facet_ranges={}},highlighting={},spellcheck={suggestions={correctlySpelled=false}}}

Comment: What does the query look like being sent to solr?

Comment: Also, How is the solr related to autocomplete search function. when i try searching for 'Attention deficit hyperactivity disorder' , the autocomplete works. But not otherwise i.e when i search for ADHD

Comment: May i know is there any other configuration changes to be done in the solr for the synonym search and autocomplete to work both ways.